# Django exists query not work in if and else clause?

Tags: mysql, django

In given below if Medicine table consists medicine_name then query execute fine, but when medicine name doesn't exist on the Corresponding table then error is occured.

> Matching Query Doesn't Exists

views.py Code

```
@api_view(['POST'])
    def addPeople(request):
    m = People()
    m.bp_no = request.POST['bp_no']
    m.name = request.POST['name']
    m.corporation_name = request.POST['corporation_name']
    m.medicine_name = request.POST['medicine_name']
    m.no_of_medicine = request.POST['no_of_medicine']

    existing = Medicine.objects.get(medicine_name=m.medicine_name).no_of_medicine -  int(m.no_of_medicine)
    p_key = Medicine.objects.get(medicine_name=m.medicine_name).id
    if Medicine.objects.filter(medicine_name=m.medicine_name).exists():
      if existing > 0:
      m.save()       
      Medicine.objects.filter(id=p_key).update(no_of_medicine=existing)
      return Response({"message": "Successfully Recorded"})
      else:
       return Response({"message": "Not much Medicine Stored"})
    else:
       return Response({"message": "Medicine is not Stored"})
```

models.py

```
class People(models.Model):
    bp_no = models.IntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
    name = models.CharField(blank=False,null=False,max_length=200)
    corporation_name = models.CharField(blank=False,null=False,max_length=200)
    medicine_name = models.CharField(blank=False,null=False,max_length=200)
    no_of_medicine = models.IntegerField()

class Medicine(models.Model):
    medicine_name = models.CharField(null=False,blank=False,max_length=200)
    no_of_medicine = models.IntegerField(null=False,blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.medicine_name
```

Error Traceback: When Medicine table doesn't contains the corresponding filter name then This error will be shown

```
    Internal Server Error: /api/add-people/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MonirHossain\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\MonirHossain\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MonirHossain\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MonirHossain\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MonirHossain\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\MonirHossain\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\MonirHossain\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\MonirHossain\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MonirHossain\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\django\backend\medirecords\api\views.py", line 37, in addPeople
    existing = Medicine.objects.get(medicine_name=m.medicine_name).no_of_medicine -  int(m.no_of_medicine)       
  File "C:\Users\MonirHossain\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MonirHossain\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 435, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
api.models.Medicine.DoesNotExist: Medicine matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Please share the *full* view, the relevant models and the *full* traceback, likely the error is caused before this code part.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem now Check Please

Comment: The *full error traceback* please.

Comment: @deceze Now please check

Comment: Well, no object exists in the database that matches `Medicine.objects.get(medicine_name=m.medicine_name)`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but purely in terms of handling objects not found, I have a suggestion you can try to simplify the conditions / flow.

#### .get(): Wrap in `try` / `except`

[`get(*args, **kwargs)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get) raises [`Model.DoesNotExist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/class/#django.db.models.Model.DoesNotExist) when not found.

When there's a not found, you need to determine how you want to handle it. For example, you can have a default fallback value, or raise an error.

In this case the code would fail if the existing medicine wasn't found, so I will have it raise.

```py
@api_view(["POST"])
def addPeople(request):
    medicine_name = request.POST["medicine_name"]
    try:
        medicine = Medicine.objects.get(medicine_name=medicine_name)
    except Medicine.DoesNotExist:
        return Response({"message": "Not much Medicine Stored"})
    m = People()
    m.bp_no = request.POST["bp_no"]
    m.name = request.POST["name"]
    m.corporation_name = request.POST["corporation_name"]
    m.medicine_name = medicine_name
    m.no_of_medicine = request.POST["no_of_medicine"]

    existing = medicine.no_of_medicine - int(m.no_of_medicine)

    p_key = medicine.id
    if medicine.exists():
        if existing > 0:
            m.save()
            medicine.num_of_medicine = existing
            medicine.save(update_fields=["num_of_medicine"])
            return Response({"message": "Successfully Recorded"})
        else:
            return Response({"message": "Not much Medicine Stored"})
    else:
        return Response({"message": "Medicine is not Stored"})
```

- Move object check earlier

  Since the request relies on `Medicine`, this is should be caught early as possible.
- Uses `try`/`catch` as `.get()` will always raise when object is not found

  The alternative is to do [`.exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) or [`filter(*args, **kwargs)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#filter) + [`.first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#first)
- Update dependent model via [`Model.save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) and limit field updated to `num_of_medicine` via `update_fields`.

#### `get_object_or_404()`

[`get_object_or_404(klass, *args, **kwargs)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) can also be used in lieu of the earlier `try`/`catch` block:

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

medicine = get_object_or_404(Medicine.objects.all(), medicine_name=m.medicine_name)
existing = medicine.no_of_medicine - int(m.no_of_medicine)
```

### Final note

I'm assuming this is an example, but it also may be good to validate `request.POST["no_of_medicine"]` in the POST data against a backend source of truth to make sure it's not faked.